# Diferença entre Absolute Expiration e Sliding Expiration

Tags: c#, asp.net, arquitetura-de-software, cache

Estou fazendo uma POC com cache genérico em C# e segui um modelo que mostra **Absolute Expiration** e **Sliding Expiration**. Algum poderia me explicar melhor estes conceitos?

```
            //This is for Absolute Expiration
        string strCache = GenericCustomCache.GetItemToCache<string>("String", "Poc Cache Teste 1!", DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(20));
        DateTime dtCache = GenericCustomCache.GetItemToCache<DateTime>("DT", DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(20));

        Response.Write("Absolute Expiration<br/>");
        Response.Write(strCache + dtCache.ToString() + "<br/>");

        //This is for Sliding Expiration
        string strCache1 = GenericCustomCache.GetItemToCache<string>("String1", "Good Moring!", TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
        DateTime dtCache1 = GenericCustomCache.GetItemToCache<DateTime>("DT1", DateTime.Now, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));

        Response.Write("Sliding Expiration<br/>");
        Response.Write(strCache1 + dtCache1.ToString() + "<br/>");
```

Classe genérica:

```
 internal static T GetItemToCache<T>(string key, object cacheObject, DateTime absoluteExpiration)
    {
        return GetItemToCache<T>(key, cacheObject, absoluteExpiration, Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is used to get item from cache using absoluteExpiration.
    /// </summary>
    internal static T GetItemToCache<T>(string key, object cacheObject, TimeSpan slidingExpiration)
    {
        return GetItemToCache<T>(key, cacheObject, Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, slidingExpiration);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is used to get item from cache.
    /// </summary>
    internal static T GetItemToCache<T>(string key, object cacheObject, DateTime absoluteExpiration, TimeSpan slidingExpiration)
    {
        T customObj;

        if (HttpRuntime.Cache[key] != null)
        {
            customObj = (T)HttpRuntime.Cache[key];
        }
        else
        {
            //DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30)
            HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(key, cacheObject, null, absoluteExpiration, slidingExpiration);
            customObj = (T)HttpRuntime.Cache[key];
        }

        return customObj;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ambos permitem você configurar o tempo de expiração de seus dados no cache, pelo que entendi [aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/4y13wyk9(v=vs.110).aspx), funciona assim:

**absoluteExpiration:** O tempo em que o objeto inserido expira e é removido do cache independente de quando o objeto é acessado.

Exemplo:

```
string cacheData = "Seu dado";
Cache.Insert("AbsoluteCacheKey", cacheData, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1), System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
```

Seu dado será removido do cache após 1 minuto.

**slidingExpiration:** O tempo em que o objeto será removido do cache se ele não foi acessado.

Exemplo:

```
string cacheData = "Seu dado";
Cache.Insert("SlidingExpiration", cacheData, null, System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
```

Seu dado será removido do cache após 1 minuto, porém se ele for acessando faltando 30 segundos para expirar, será aguardado mais 1 minuto antes de removê-lo.